# Adding additional static Ip adresses

Tags: steam, cache

I tried to make my own Steam Cache like it is shown in https://youtu.be/gk1eKPRLaJA?t=411 but even after I added all IP adresses they did not show up when executing ifconfig.

My questions are now:
1. Is this normal or do I need additional (virtual) Nics for additional IP adresses?
2. How can I set the IP adresses and the gateway using the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit /etc/network/interfaces.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add the required details.

After that. Save and close.

Then:

```
systemctl restart networking
```